# Linaro gcc fails on Windows

Tags: cygwin, cross-platform, linaro

I'm trying to bringup gcc-linaro-7.3.1 on windows.

I've downloaded gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-i686-mingw32_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar from Linaro site, extracted using tar on Cygwin, but when I try to run "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc.exe" it seems that nothing happens.
when I try to run from Windows cmd, I get an error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000022)".

any Ideas?

Comment: what is the output of `file aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc.exe` ?

Comment: there's no output. I've tried also --help flag, still nothing.

Comment: You have a broken installation. `File` belongs to base category so it is always installed. Try re-installing the `cygwin` and `zlib0` packages after closing all cygwin process, including any services.

Comment: @matzeri thanks, you were right, seems something got corrupted, I've used 7zip to unpack the tar. cygwin tar didn't work